# Cordova facebook plugin Already Authorized message

Tags: facebook, cordova

I am using the Cordova Facebook plugin in my Intel XDK project (targeted for iPhone).  The login works, however, there is an "annoyance" I am trying to get rid of.  After the first login, subsequent attempts to login result in the usual redirect to a Safari page (which is ok).  The page displays "You have already authorized [my app name]." User can press OK or cancel.  The user is not being asked to login to Facebook, so I presume a cookie or something is set on Safari (which is Ok).  Is there a way to avoid this confirmation page?

I ask cause When I use Facebook logins on regular websites, the subsequent logins don't show this message, rather just redirect the flow back to the application.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this one? Because I'm facing the same problem and I can't figure out how to solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, by employing the getLoginStatus API ([GetStatus](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#get-status)). I.e. now I first check the status returned from the getLoginStatuscall first. Only if not connected, then I call the login method.